# Multiple "graphql" instances with npm link

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, graphql-js

When I connect my other module to the main application using npm link, an error appears: "Cannot use GraphQLObjectType "Query" from another module or realm."

Graphql versions are the same in both modules.
There are no other graphics folders in the node_modules folder
All versions of graphql in npm ls are identical. What could be the problem?
GraphQL added to peerDependencies in the plug-in
The options with the removal of package-lock, resolution and npm dedupe did not work. And the problem only occurs with npm link.

Comment: `npm link` in my experience just doesn't work well with complex dependency trees. I use it for the simplest (usually 0-dependency) libraries. A reason is that all of your dependency's `node_modules` gets linked into the tree, so there's no de-duplication happening.

Comment: "*All versions of graphql in npm ls are identical.*" - that doesn't matter, the real problem is that you have multiple `graphql` libraries in the `node_modules` folders at all